# Python: how to pass string to postgres command using psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a problem passing a string to a query in python for postgresql. In particular I have the following script that works perfectly:

```
y = 'test'
for i in un:
    crs = conn.cursor()
    query = """
        select * 
        FROM  test
        WHERE test.vin_id = %s
    ;"""
    s_id = i
    crs.execute(query,[s_id])
    s_out = crs.fetchall()
```

but if I change `test` with the variable `y` it gives me an error.

```
for i in un:
    crs = conn.cursor()
    query = """
        select * 
        FROM  %s
        WHERE %s.vin_id = %s
    ;"""
    s_id = i
    crs.execute(query,[y,y,s_id])
    s_out = crs.fetchall()

ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "'test'"
LINE 3:         FROM  'test'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AsIs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extensions.html#psycopg2.extensions.AsIs):

```
from psycopg2.extensions import AsIs
for i in un:
    crs = conn.cursor()
    query = """
        select * 
        FROM  %s
        WHERE %s.vin_id = %s
    ;"""
    s_id = i
    crs.execute(query,[AsIs(y),AsIs(y),s_id])
    s_out = crs.fetchall()
```

Comment: You forgot to use `AsIs`: `crs.execute(query,[AsIs(y),AsIs(y),s_id])`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it does not work and I have the same problem when I try to put sentences in the middle, for instance:

```
query1 = """
SELECT * 
FROM test1 
WHERE %s LIKE '%'  || vin_id || '%' 
;"""    
crs1 = conn.cursor()
crs1.execute(query1, [s_id])
```